# Convert string containing an array to array object

Tags: java, arrays, string

Hello I have a string containing an array! I want to be able to construct this into an array but I cannot find any methods for doing so! Can someone help me, this is what my string looks like

[111111,111111,111111,111111,111111,111111,111111]

Comment: You're going to need to parse the string: start by removing the square brackets and then look for the commas (which will be your delimiters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take out the square brackets then use the string split method, giving ',' as a delimiter.

```
String str = "[111111,111111,111111,111111,111111,111111,111111]"
//remove the brackets
//as backslash mentioned, str.substring is a better approach than using str.replaceAll with regex
str = str.substring(1, str.length()-1);
//split the string into an array
String[] strArray = str.split(",");
```

Comment: To remove brackets you can avoid regexes by using `str = str.substring(1, str.length()-1)`

Comment: Thats a good idea that will solve my problem! how would I loop on each iem to do this though?

Comment: @RyanMcCleave `for(String s : strArray) { ... }`

Comment: I dont understand this? how would this recognise each of the 6 number groupings in the string?

Comment: The str.split method splits the overall large string into substring, each delimited by the ",". This results in an Array that contains each number grouping.

Comment: I need to loop on every 6 digit number in that string forcing the group into an int array

Comment: ahhhhhhhh I thought it just took and stored a chunk! Thank you this will more than help me! Thank you everyone!